# skip preamble screens in cygwin?

Tags: installation, cygwin

Not unrarely I'll want to isntall a new package in cygwin. When I launch the installer, I have to go through a few screens where I specify the mirror host, the download directory, and all that. Is there a way just to skip all that preliminary stuff, and go straight to the package selection screen?

Answer (score 3):

Yep:

```
setup -M
```

A shortcut is a convenient way to invoke setup.exe like that: just add the `-M` to the shortcut target. Also see `setup --help` for more command line options. You might be interested in the `-P` option for specifying the packages to install on the command line.

Comment: This isn't listed in the switched in the FAQ: http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.cli Anyway setup doesn't launch when I try to the `-M` switch.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of setup?